# How do I get AutoArchive to work in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving

I'm using Outlook 2007. Tools > Options > Other > AutoArchive says "Run AutoArchive every 1 days". The Deleted Items folder properties says "Archive this folder using these settings: Clean out items older than 1 Months / Permanently delete old items".

Nevertheless, I'm seeing three-month-old mail in Deleted Items. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know, if this setting exists in Outlook 2007, but you may need to enable "Archive or delete old items". This is necessary for Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016 at least ([more details](https://superuser.com/a/1579629/1077440)).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "Prompt before archiving" setting checked? If it's checked, it won't start archiving without your say so.

The quick way to verify that your Archive settings themselves are not at fault is to manually trigger the AutoArchive process. If you manually trigger it and everything archives correctly, then you've got it setup properly.

Comment: I don't have "Prompt before archiving" checked. The archiving happens fine if I request it manually. Those facts make the situation all the more puzzling.